# Using Map + Rest Operator (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

This function does what i wanted it to do but not what i expected it to do. I expected it to create two arrays since ...args creates an array of the passed arguments and map() does something to each value of the array it is connected to and stores the results in a new array. Can someone tell me why this function doesnt create two arrays?

```js
let practiceFunc = (...args) => {
 let arr = args.map((e) => {
  return e + 1
 })
  
 return arr ;
} 

console.log(practiceFunc(1,2,3)) ;
document.write(practiceFunc(1,2,3)) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "doesn't create two arrays". What output were you expecting, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen i was expecting an array with the numbers 1 2 3 as elements and then an array created by the map array containing elements 2 3 4

Comment: `args` is the `[1,2,3]` array and `arr` is the `[2,3,4]` array. Both get created, and only `arr` is returned.

Comment: @ggorlen yes thank you jack helped me understand that and you just solidified it in my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does create two arrays, but you only ever use one - `arr`, the array that is returned from the function. `args` is used as well, but just as the array used in the `map` - you could easily omit it and use `arguments` (however an ES5 function is required for this as arrow functions do not have their orwn `arguments`, and you would have to extract the values using `Object.values`):

```js
let practiceFunc = function() {
  let arr = Object.values(arguments).map((e) => {
    return e + 1
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(practiceFunc(1, 2, 3));
document.write(practiceFunc(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: oh yeah youre right it does thats how the function is able to use the map() method. I learned this in the es6 section of freeCodeCamp are you sure that i need an es5 function?

Comment: @iamlearningtocode That's a privilege that is unlocked with 15 reputation, so keep asking good questions and you will unlock the privilege in no time.

Comment: i didnt mean to disrespect you when i asked if you were sure about needing an es5 function. youre right actually "Arrow functions do not have an own arguments binding in their scope; no arguments object is created when calling them."

Comment: It's OK @iamlearningtocode - asking is the best form of learning.

Comment: "*you could easily omit it and use `arguments`*" - that makes no sense. There's nothing wrong with rest parameter syntax, the arguments object is out of fashion for a reason. And you should use `Array.from()` (which respects order) instead of `Object.values()`. But it's useless anyway - both of them create a temporary array as well, so nothing is gained here.

Comment: but does this matter @Bergi => "Arrow functions do not have an own arguments binding in their scope; no arguments object is created when calling them."

Comment: @iamlearningtocode Given that you probably should not use `arguments` anyway, it does not matter